# Htaccess re-write code conflict

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a conflict with my htaccess file.

I´m using the following code to remove the php handles:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Everything works well EXCEPT for one subdirectory. When the php handle is removed, it turns out that the ¨handle-less¨ name shares the same name as en existing folder and as a result, the directory for that folder is being displayed, rather than the intended php page. I would rather avoid having to change the folder name especially if this is something that can be addressed from the htaccess file.

*(I'm rather a beginner when it comes to coding... so I'm not sure how to best address this issue.)*

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  said : if it is a directory, do not do the rewrite rule

Edit :

Could you try only :

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ /$1.php [NC]
```

This *should* rewrite all the requests with no dots inside to the php file

Comment: I am not too sure about the %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php stuff, but the !-d condition was what was messing around

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f ` seems to make the website unusable. I get the following message _Not Found
The requested URL /index.php.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request._  

When I add back the `.php` the site functions again, however I am still getting the same problem as before.